# Linux: Loopback incoming packets on an interface

Tags: linux, networking, routes, ip, iptables

What is the best possible way to send packets coming on an interface back to the same interface without changing anything in the packet. I want to have a loopback effect for the actual traffic coming on one of my interfaces e.g `eth0`

Comment: What would you have the destination MAC address of the reflected packet be? If identical to the incoming packet, the reflected packet won't go far.

Comment: @Celada I want exactly the original packet with the destination MAC intact. I can handle the mac issue when i get the packet back.

Comment: @auny, why are you doing this?  It sounds like you're trying to craft a MITM attack.

Comment: @MikePennington, Not really. I am trying to build a dummy loopback for a VM. Basically i want to model a network service that forwards a packet from one interface to another but i want it to return on the same interface. Do you have any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: @auny: if the packet is unmodified then it *cannot* return on the same interface - the source and destination MAC addresses will be reversed.

Comment: @auny: Perhaps we could help you more if you mentioned what your [real problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) is at a higher level - this kind of network packet manipulation is typically very fragile and rarely (if ever) the Right Thing(TM) to do...

Comment: @thkala, I am trying to model a network service, which takes a packet, looks at it, and sends it back the same interface. It might even decide to drop it. The point to focus here is returning on the same interface. It could be a kind of a firewall. There are many physical network test equipment that provide such physical loopbacks.

Comment: @thkala, Ok lets say that we are OK with the MAC addresses being swapped,then again the question stands, How will i do it?

Comment: @auny, show us your code... what have you tried?

Comment: @MikePennington, I dont really have the code for it. I asked the question before doing that. But i think what i can do is to make L2 raw sockets either in userspace or kernel, receive packets on some linux net_device and send them back myself.

Comment: @MikePennington, My intention of asking the question was to find out a non-programatical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can easily achieve this with Python/Scapy. Something like

`sniff(iface="eth0", prn=lambda x: sendp(x, iface="eth0"))`

should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this easily with a physical interface. I used the tap module for this purpose, though. It's quite simple: I create a new tap interface, and my program writes back everything that is read from the device. I used this to test a proprietary network protocol - so it might or might not work for what you intend to do. The code is quite simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>

#include <linux/if_tun.h>

#define DEVNAME "gnlo0"

static int tun_alloc(char *dev)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int fd, ret;

    if ((fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)) < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));

    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TAP;
    if (*dev)
        strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);

    ret = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *)&ifr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        close(fd);
        perror("ioctl TUNSETIFF");
        return ret;
    }
    strcpy(dev, ifr.ifr_name);
    return fd;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd = -1;
    int ret = 1;
    char dev[IFNAMSIZ];
    strncpy(dev, DEVNAME, IFNAMSIZ - 1);
    printf("opening %s\n", dev);

    fd = tun_alloc(dev);
    if (fd < 0)
        goto out;

    char buf[512];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf) - 1,
             "ip addr flush dev %s; ip link set dev %s up", dev, dev);
    if (system(buf) < 0) {
        perror("system");
        goto out;
    }

    while (1) {
        unsigned char packet[65535];
        int len = read(fd, packet, sizeof(packet));
        if (len < 0) {
            perror("read");
            goto out;
        }
        printf("incoming packet [%d octets]\n", len);

        len = write(fd, packet, len);
        printf("fed back packet [%d octets]\n", len);
    }
    ret = 0;

out:
    if (fd >= 0)
        close(fd);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed code. But I think I can do what I want by creating an L2 raw socket. In that way i can have complete control even before the stack kicks in